# Powershell $Credential object to prevent the need for user interaction

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a new object that I can pass the username/password too so that I don't require user interaction when speaking to the rest API i am working with.

Microsoft has a handy example (Example 7) of this found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6

However when using this method I receive the following:

```
    New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument 
    count: 
    "2".
    At line:17 char:15
    + ... redential = New-Object -TypeName 
    System.Management.Automation.PSCrede ...
    +                 
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], 
    MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShel 
    l.Commands.NewObjectCommand

    Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
    argument 
    '$null'.
    At line:21 char:1
    + Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri $Credential #-Credential $cre 
    ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], 
    ParameterB 
    indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
    mands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Just so that you can verify my code, it's basically the same as the Microsoft example:

```
    $Uri = 'A url to a rest api'
    $User = "A Username"
    $PWD = "A Password"
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName 
    System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWD 


    #Invokes rest get request to rabbitmq uri                            
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri $Credential
```

With the error received I imagine I'm not passing the New-Object command something it is expecting?

Comment: As the error message says. There is no "PSCredential" constructor that accepts two arguments of type `String` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)). The only constructor that accepts 2 arguments expects `String` and `SecureString`. So your underlying question is: How do I convert a String to a SecureString.

Comment: Thanks for this, @TobyU mentioned this as well and can see he included the same conversion that Microsoft used on their page (doh!), I am now converting the string to a SecureString using this method but am still hitting a brick wall when passing this to the Invoke-RestMethod command.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly state the parameter name, i.e. `-Credential $Credential`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `SecureString` out of the password like:

```
$User = "A Username"
$PWD = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "A Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User,$PWD)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I am now getting the following: Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
At line:21 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri $Credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterB 
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
   mands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: My code now looks like: $uri = 'a url to rest api'
$User = "a user"
$PWD = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "a password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWD 


#Invokes rest get request to rabbitmq uri                            
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri $Credential

Comment: Again thank you, but looks like im still getting the same error: Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
At line:21 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri $Credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], Parame 
   terBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

My Credential obj now looks like yours with the ()

Comment: I've updated my answer once more. You need to use the `-Credential` parameter with `Invoke-RestMethod` to provide your credentials.

Comment: oh my bad ! thanks for pointing this out. Appreciate all the help, this is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you just want to prompt for credentials:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

The parentheses run the `Get-Credential` cmdlet as an expression, which outputs a `PSCredential` object, which is used as the `-Credential` parameter's argument.